# Adding getStaticProps/getStaticPaths to dynamic route generates 404 page

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm new to Next.js so I created a simple news website so I can read an article by using this route:

`/[category]/[article]`

This is the structure of `pages`:

```
_pages
__[category]
____index.jsx
____[...all].jsx
```

This is `[...all].jsx`:

```
export default function Article() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { category, all } = router.query;

  return (
    <>
      {category}/{all[0]}
    </>
  );
}
```

But when I added this `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`, I started getting 404:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  return { props: { params } };
}
```

I was looking everywhere online for a simple example for a nested dynamic routing with `getStaticProps`. For some reasons the official docs skip on that. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is twofold. First, you're passing an empty array in `paths` - meaning no paths will be generated at build time. Second, you've set `fallback: false` - meaning no new paths will be generated at request time.

You can either pass the paths you want to generate at build time in the `paths` array. Or, simply replace the `fallback` value with `fallback: 'blocking'` to solve the 404 issue.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [],
        fallback: 'blocking'
    };
}
```

The above `getStaticPaths` will not generate any paths during build time. Instead, it will statically generate each path when they're first requested.